# How Debuggers Find Expressions From Code Lines

Tags: c, linux, debugging

A debugger gets a line number of an expression and <strike>translates it into an program address</strike>, what does the implementation look like? I want to implement this in a program I'm writing and the most promising library I've found to accomplish this is [libbfd](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/bfd/). All I would need is the address of the expression, and I can wait for it with `ptrace(2)`. I can imagine that the debugger looks for the function name from the `C` file within the executable, but after that I'm lost.

Does anyone know? I don't need a code example, just enough info so that I can get an idea.
And I don't mind architecture-specific answers, the only ones I really care about are Arm and x86-64.

Comment: If you're brave you could have a look at the gdb source - It's available [online](http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/gdb/?cvsroot=src) and will obviously do what you want. Somewhere.

Comment: Are you asking how a debugger translates an address in the *compiled binary* to a line number in the *source code*? Your phrasing is confusing.

Comment: @brice, Lol, I am not that brave. I've never been able to look at more than 1000 - 2000 lines of code without losing it. I guess I should try though

Comment: @Rakkun, I don't really care. Which way is easier? I'm probably looking for the way a debugger does it.

Comment: @brice, I did find [this](http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/~checkout~/src/gdb/breakpoint.c?rev=1.765&content-type=text/plain&cvsroot=src), which may help

Comment: The debugger does not "get a line number of an expression and translate it into a program address", it merely looks up the information already stored in the binary by the compiler and linker.

Comment: okay, I was just guessing that's what it did. Can you be more specific? Or share a link? What's the information it looks up?

Comment: @TaylorFlores See the answer below about DWARF2. Also Google for "stabs" debugging info, which is older than DWARF2, but is still out there in the wild... There are probably others, too...

Comment: I did. I see what you mean now. I found the manual on DWARF2, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the DWARF2 format to try to understand how the mapping is done. Do consider how DWARF2 is vast and complex. It's not for everyone, but reading about it might satisfy your curiosity faster and more easily than reading the source for GCC/GDB.

Comment: I found this [this](http://www.dwarfstd.org/doc/Debugging%20using%20DWARF-2012.pdf) link which is pretty useful. Thanks! I'm going to wait and see what other answers I get, but this helps a lot

Comment: Yep, that's the official doc. If nobody posts a better answer, I'll expand mine a bit tomorrow.